# how to fix awning windows won't close

Tags: windows

I rent a double story town house. The window in the bed room is awning windows, and there is a problem that the crank is not closing to the end; there is still a gap that keeps window a bit open. So wind still get to the room.

The bed room is in the 2nd floor so i cannot close it from outside.

is there anyway i can close this window? I cannot fix the crank because I don't have the tools or the experience. i just want this window to be shut

[image]

Comment: If you post a close-up photo of the crank, guide, and latch mechanism(s) we might be able to help you fix it or at least to disengage the crank so the window could close completely...

Comment: it is the landlord's responsibility to repair the problem

Comment: maybe you can pull the window closed using some kind of hook or sucker,  but talk to the landlord too.

Comment: On most of those windows the crank is held in with 2 screws, you will probably will need to Unscrew them then the window will close. I would not pull on the window it may bend the bar that attaches from the crank to the window. Is the crank binding? Handle spinning and not moving? A bit more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have kitchen windows that close with a crank. Sometimes debris gets caught where the window meets the frame or sometimes paint or caulk may have settled there. Check to see if there is debris where the window sash meets the frame.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and my fix is to remove the screen and pull the window in. If it feels like it won’t pull, simply turn the crank a few more times.

The screen is held in by little turn tabs so it is easy to pop out and back in.